# Nginx serving non-secure resources on https domain

Tags: magento, ssl

I'm having some issues setting up a server with an SSL certificate. I was able to install the certificate just fine and restarted the nginx service. However, when I attempt to load my website, I see that all img, css and js files are being retrieved with http instead of https. This is a Magento website. Is there something wrong with my conf file?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://my-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/my-domain/my-domain_com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my-domain/my-domain_com.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/magento.local-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/magento.local-error.log;

    server_name my-domain.com;
    root /var/www/my-domain;

    include conf/magento_rewrites.conf;
    include conf/magento_security.conf;

    # PHP handler
    location ~ \.php {
      ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
      if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

      ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
      fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
      fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;

      # By default, only handle fcgi without caching
      include conf/magento_fcgi.conf;
    }

    # 404s are handled by front controller
    location @magefc {
      rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    # Last path match hands to magento or sets global cache-control
    location / {
      ## Maintenance page overrides front controller
      index index.html index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ @magefc;
      expires 24h;
    }

    rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

    location /lib/minify/ {
        allow all;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is likely to be an issue with your configuration of magneto, not nginx or openssl. I'd suggest retagging it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe cause this is how they are called, if you need to serve every thing as https, i would create an empty server that listens on `80` and redirect to https

```
server {
    # listen 80; delete this part
    listen 443 ssl;
    # the rest of the config
}
# add this server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / # or a more specific location '~ \.(jpg|css|js|jpeg|png|gif)' {
        return https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

or just fix the css location, it might be an absolute URL with http